# MySql MyIsam table with fulltext search wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard, myisam, full-text-indexing

I created two tables with two different storage engines with same columns:
table1(id,col1,col2) MyIsam
table2(id,col1,col2) innodb
every table contain according 1700000

I created full text index for (col1,col2) in the 2 tables
I have 2 keywords that I need to extract results containing them:
'school' and 'bus'
I am using wildcard to extract them
select * from table1 where match(col1,col2) against ('+scho*+bus*')

- mean complete truncated word
- mean and

in table1(MyIsam) the result is incorrect,
26573 total, Query took 0.0009 sec
rows contain any keyword 'school' or 'bus'

in table2(innodb) the result is correct, 
369 total, Query took 0.0420 sec
rows contain the two words 'school' and 'bus'

anyone can help me?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: I don't know the solution off-hand, but why not try to change the table type? Is there a reason that table1 must be MyISAM?

Comment: Check  [ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len); if the minimum word length is 4, "bus" will be ignored

Comment: MyISAM is very fast search VS innodb and if working with more than one pc connecting to the same MYSql server, it may make a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting space before + 
match(col1,col2) against ('+scho* +bus*')

but I have another issue, if I want to search by any keyword end with any thing, it can't be displayed,
if I search by keyword "School"
match(col1,col2) against ('+*chool*')
0 rows